# Javascript Adding If Statement In Select tag ID

Tags: javascript

This is my drop down using select and the id is **beh_type**

```
<select class="form-control" id="beh_type">
<option value="0">Auto</option>
<option value="1">Man</option>
</select>
```

and this is my multiple select list and the id is **mult_type**

```
<select multiple="multiple" class="form-control" id="mult_type">
<option value="0">Auto</option>
<option value="1">Man</option>
</select>
```

and this is my JavaScript code for single click using if condition and the code to be executed for mult_type not for beh_type

```
if($("select").attr("id") == "mult_type"){        
$("select").mousedown(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

            var select = this;
        var scroll = select.scrollTop;

        e.target.selected = !e.target.selected;

        setTimeout(function(){select.scrollTop = scroll;}, 0);

        $(select).focus();}
    }).mousemove(function(e){e.preventDefault()});
```

Comment: What is the problem here?

Comment: the JS  should work for mult_type id only I.E the JS code is used  to select multiple items in single click instead of ctrl click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need that event for `select` with `id` value as `mult_type` then add those event using the `id` selector:

```
$("#mult_type").mousedown(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var select = this;
    var scroll = select.scrollTop;

    e.target.selected = !e.target.selected;

    setTimeout(function(){select.scrollTop = scroll;}, 0);

   $(select).focus();
}).mousemove(function(e){e.preventDefault()});
```

Comment: works fine can i do this way $("#mult_type",#mult_type1").mousedown(function(e)

Comment: You could even use `$("select#mult_type").mousedown` to specify the select you want to use, but this just the id works as well. After all, I think the OP should learn more about jquery selectors: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change the position of "if". The correct code would be

```
$("select").mousedown(function(e){
 if($("select").attr("id") == "mult_type"){    
    e.preventDefault();
    var select = this;
    var scroll = select.scrollTop;

    e.target.selected = !e.target.selected;

    setTimeout(function(){select.scrollTop = scroll;}, 0);

    $(select).focus();}
}).mousemove(function(e){e.preventDefault()});
```